# Spring Batch : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

As part of a Spring Batch job, we are processing 1TB worth of data to our system.

After the process running for 4-5hours getting the OOM, when the job is terminated ideally the java heap has to be cleared. and when restarted it should start on the fresh heap. but for some reason when checked with jcmd -gccapacity OGC and OC values are showing full.
How do we clear the Heap and restart the job as good as new run?
This is production env, in lower env we had very less data so did not face any issue. meanwhile i am debugging the memory leaks in code.
NOTE: We already used the -Xmx to 8GB.

```
NGCMN    NGCMX     NGC     S0C   S1C       EC      OGCMN      OGCMX       OGC         OC       MCMN     MCMX      MC     CCSMN    CCSMX     CCSC    YGC    FGC   CGC
     0.0 4194304.0 220160.0    0.0    0.0 220160.0        0.0  4194304.0  3974144.0  3974144.0      0.0 1224704.0 203840.0      0.0 1048576.0  28672.0    112     4    83
```

Please advice. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your JVM the command line should also contain a "scheme" for using [the G1 garbage collector](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html). This should be on the command-line or within configuration files for the [program startup **-XX:+UseG1GC**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/gctuning/garbage-first-garbage-collector.htm#JSGCT-GUID-CE6F94B6-71AF-45D5-829E-DEADD9BA929D) followed by [parameters of a scheme](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/g1gc.html) on how to share memory for cleanup (runtime behavior) by the G1. It is usually set when -Xms and -Xmx and -Xss are used to assign and reserve RAM for the JVM on starup.
In code, after large data routines are finished  , using System.gc() requests the garbage collector take a look to clean up at its discretion(it will in near future).

```
intx ThreadStackSize                          = 1024 (1kb)
size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 8183087104 (approx 7.8 mb)
InitialHeapSize                          = 511705088 (approx 500kb)
```

**1024 bytes = 1kb**

**1024kb = 1mb**

**1024mb = 1gb**

**1024 x 1024 = ( 1048576 bytes = 1mb ) x 1024 = ( 1073741824 bytes = 1gb )**

**Java command line byte values are suffixed any of k,m,g on the end of the number non case sensitive , bytes are just numbers does not need a letter suffix.**

Comment: we are using Java 11 , i think that will use default as G1GC right?

Answer (score -1):

````
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                  = 1024                                   {pd product} {default}
   size_t ErgoHeapSizeLimit                        = 0                                         {product} {default}
   size_t HeapSizePerGCThread                      = 43620760                                  {product} {default}
   size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 511705088                                 {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t LargePageHeapSizeThreshold               = 134217728                                 {product} {default}
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 8183087104                                {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonNMethodCodeHeapSize                   = 7594288                                {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonProfiledCodeHeapSize                  = 122031976                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ProfiledCodeHeapSize                     = 122031976                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
   size_t ShenandoahSoftMaxHeapSize                = 0                                      {manageable} {default}
     intx ThreadStackSize                          = 1024                                   {pd product} {default}
     bool UseG1GC                                  = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
    ```
````

Comment: These are the values i have.. not sure . what i am missing. Please advice

Comment: true, but with it requires to be a set of parameters that assist mapping out the RAM space reserved for the JVM , it seems there too. Note the word "reserved" -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=10 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20" ,  The machine also needs 500mb left over for its OS , then everything else can be used if there are no other programs running aside the basic supports of the OS. Take a look at that, you can watch garbage collection and RAM used. Go to your /bin folder of your jdk and click on and execute jvisualvm https://visualvm.github.io/gettingstarted.html use "profile".

Comment: Just again, if you have methods that manipulated massive quantities of data inside the one routine, it cannot do anything until you finish with the method. After such a method should have System.gc() in the code run or if it was a void method at the end of the method. Its the old way but it requires some of that. Best practice is to break down complex methods containing large quantities of data is to remove as many pieces of action into other methods so they can be thrown to the dump to indicate, e.g in a loop replace the work code into a method.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding this info as an answer. As this is not one.